# iTunes / About This Mac Storage Capacity Bars

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, graph, itunes, capacity

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to recreate the capacity bars in Lion, like so...

http://thenextweb.com/files/2011/07/about-this-mac-storage.png

I've seen third party apps (such as Windows Phone 7 Connector) using an identical control.  Is there an official way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a custom view. So the only "official" way to do it is to subclass NSView and go crazy in drawRect:.

You might as well start with the [official documentation on the subject](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html).

After that, there are numerous tutorials and such on the web. [This one](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/intro_to_quartz_two/) isn't half bad.

Comment: Thanks for steering me in the right direction.  I'm new to cocoa programming, so it's a bit hard to know where to go sometimes.

Comment: @Stefan: I made a list of the most important links: http://boredzo.org/cocoa-links-card

Comment: I'm a bit late in replying. Thanks for that list, Peter :D